# Format text with indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing multi-lines in the file.

```
Number  Name
        Jack
```

The first line is a header.
I am going to write lines like the above format.
If the number is null, I am writing a line like this.

```
file.print "Jack".indentation("Number".length + 2)
```

There are 2 spaces between `Number` and `Name` in the header.
But it is showing like this since the length 6 spaces are not the same as "Number".

```
Number  Name
         Jack
```

Is there any solution to format better?

Comment: What file output are your writing to? It seems that a normal plain text file the width of a space character should be the same as any letter. You should also checkout https://apidock.com/ruby/String/ljust

Comment: @yule I am writing to a normal plain text file. yes, a space character is the same but the length of "Number" is 6 but this is not the same as 6 spaces in the file so it is showing wrong.

Comment: With a monospace font, "number" and "      " are the same size, your example has 9 spaces.

Comment: If you want to have correct indentation then use a monospace font, you can't do much with a simple text file.